# Visual Studio Code Data Viewer Issues

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, delay, vscode-extensions

I use Visual Studio Code for all of my programming in Python, and rely heavily on the Interactive Window and Data Viewer. I usually work with large data sets, though this has only marginally affected run times in the past. For some reason recently, when clicking on a data frame in the Interactive Window, a Data Viewer tab will appear but not fully load the data frame. The blue line signaling that it is working just keeps scrolling across the top of the screen interminably. Everything else seems to work fine, and the programs are still able to run, however I can't really continue developing them.

Does anyone have any tips for how to make the Data Viewer work again? I have already uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio Code, and have disabled extensions as well.

Comment: Sam, Sorry, but could you provide a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by re-installing the Python extension. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this used to work in the past, most likely there is a misconfiguration. I had to

1. change the Python virtual environment
2. make sure I have installed the extension `Jupyter`
3. And also in the virtual env: `pip install Jupyter`

And it worked again